# json formatting_adding a tag to it

Tags: php, json

here is the PHP file that im using to generate the JSON with:

```
<?

$databasehost = "wbw.com";
$databasename = "wtest";
$databaseusername ="w";
$databasepassword = "123";
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `and` LIMIT 0 , 30";

$con = mysql_connect($databasehost,$databaseusername,$databasepassword) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($databasename) or die(mysql_error());
$sth = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_errno()) { 
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo $query.'\n';
    echo mysql_error(); 
}
else
{
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
}
?>
```

The problem with it is that it generates a result like this:

> [{"Reg_user_name":"nn","Username":"ns","Device
>   Code":"2366c84dead","HTTP":"https://api.ee.com/v1//306ad73427e262r9","Device
>   Name":"office"},{"Reg_user_name":"nn","Username":"nn","Device
>   Code":"2366c84dead","HTTP":"https://api.ee.com/v1/e/306ad73427e262e7","Device
>   Name":"LAB lighting"}]

BUT in order to use the JSONobject and get the elements in it I need to give JSON like follows:

> [**"Information":**{"Reg_user_name":"nn","Username":"ns","Device
>   Code":"2366c84dead","HTTP":"https://api.ee.com/v1//306ad73427e262r9","Device
>   Name":"office"},{"Reg_user_name":"nn","Username":"nn","Device
>   Code":"2366c84dead","HTTP":"https://api.ee.com/v1/e/306ad73427e262e7","Device
>   Name":"LAB lighting"}]

I want to know that what I have to add in the PHP file to get that data with the added "**information:**" tag to it automatically using the above PHP file.

Comment: `["Information":{....}, {...}]` is not valid JSON

Comment: that is your own format and not a json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want one index, you can change this

```
 $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
```

into this

```
 $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
 $json = array(
     'information' => $rows,
 );
    print json_encode($json);
```

just add string index to the array the json encoder will automatically convert it

Answer (score 2):

check this

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) 
{
  $rows['information'][] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried what nayoso posted and it worked as to what I needed and addded the information tag, now I think I can parse this json which is generated live using the JSONobject in Android